# How can I implement star rating system on multiple models in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two user models: `Company` & `Freelancer`. Each gives star rating to the other at the end of the transaction. I tried using `ratyrate` gem. But it only allows single `rater` model. Is there any way to achieve this?
Ratyrate generates following models taking `User` model as `rater`:

```
class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rater, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :rateable, :polymorphic => true
end

class RatingCache < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cacheable, :polymorphic => true
end

class AverageCache < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rater, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :rateable, :polymorphic => true
end

class OverallAverage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rateable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

What I have done is as follows:

```
class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rater, :class_name => "Company"
  belongs_to :rateable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  ratyrate_rater
end

class Freelancer < ActiveRecord::Base
 ratyrate_rateable "performance"
end
```

In my views, I have:

```
<%= rating_for @freelancer, 'performance' %>
```

But this only allows companies to rate freelancers. How can I achieve this in two way so that both will be able to rate each other?

Comment: have you tried this:
`class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  ratyrate_rateable "rating"
  ratyrate_rateable 
end`

`class Freelancer < ActiveRecord::Base
  ratyrate_rater
  ratyrate_rateable "rating"
end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using `acts_as_rateable` [plugin](https://github.com/r0man/acts_as_rateable) and customizing it a bit.

My final implementation looks as follows:

app/models/company.rb

```
require 'acts_as_rateable'
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_rateable
end
```

app/models/freelancer.rb

```
require 'acts_as_rateable'
class Freelancer < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_rateable
end
```

app/controllers/companies_controller.rb

```
def rate_freelancer
  @freelancer.rate_it(params[:rating], current_company)
  respond_to :html
  respond_to :js
end
```

app/controllers/freelancer_controller.rb

```
def rate_company
  @company.rate_it(params[:rating], current_freelancer)
  respond_to :html
  respond_to :js
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
post 'rate_freelancer' => 'companies#rate_freelancer'
post 'rate_company' => 'freelancers#rate_company'
```

app/models/rate.rb

```
# Table name: rates
#
#  id    :uuid             not null, primary key
#  score :float

class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings

  validates_presence_of :score
  validates_uniqueness_of :score
  validates_numericality_of :score, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 1, :less_than_or_equal_to => 10

  attr_accessor :user_id
  attr_accessor :free_text
  attr_accessor :rater_name
end
```

app/models/rating.rb

```
# Table name: ratings
#
#  id            :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  user_id       :uuid
#  rate_id       :uuid
#  rateable_id   :uuid
#  rateable_type :string
#  free_text     :text
#  rater_name    :string
#  created_at    :datetime         not null
#  updated_at    :datetime         not null

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rate
  belongs_to :rateable, :polymorphic => true

  class << self
    def parse_as(ratings, output = :xml)
      if output == :xml
        ratings.to_xml(:only => [:user_id, :free_text, :rater_name,  :created_at],
                   :methods => [:score])
      elsif output == :json
        ratings.to_json(:only => [:user_id, :free_text, :rater_name, :created_at],
                    :methods => [:score])
      end
    end
  end 
  def score
    rate.score
  end
end
```

In ratings form view:

```
<section class='rating-widget pt-2'>
  <div class='rating-stars text-center'>
      How was your experience? <br>
      <ul id='stars'>
          <li class='star' title='Poor' data-value='1'>
              <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
          </li>
          <li class='star' title='Fair' data-value='2'>
              <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
          </li>
          <li class='star' title='Good' data-value='3'>
              <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
          </li>
          <li class='star' title='Excellent' data-value='4'>
              <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
          </li>
          <li class='star' title='WOW!!!' data-value='5'>
              <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

And the script to run the show:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* 1. Visualizing things on Hover*/
    $('#stars li').on('mouseover', function() {
        var onStar = parseInt($(this).data('value'), 10); // The star currently mouse on
        // Now highlight all the stars that's not after the current hovered star
        $(this).parent().children('li.star').each(function(e) {
            if (e < onStar) {
                $(this).addClass('hover');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('hover');
            }
        });
    }).on('mouseout', function() {
        $(this).parent().children('li.star').each(function(e) {
            $(this).removeClass('hover');
        });
    });
    /* 2. Action to perform on click */
    $('#stars li').on('click', function() {
        var onStar = parseInt($(this).data('value'), 10); // The star currently selected
        var stars = $(this).parent().children('li.star');
        for (i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
            $(stars[i]).removeClass('selected');
        }
        for (i = 0; i < onStar; i++) {
            $(stars[i]).addClass('selected');
        }
        var ratingValue = parseInt($('#stars li.selected').last().data('value'), 10);
        var url = "<%= @url %>";
        var user_id = "<%= @user_id %>";
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: { value: ratingValue, user_id: user_id },
                dataType: "JSON"
            })
            .done(function() {
                window.location.reload();
            });
    });
});
</script>
```

Finally styling to make the stars shine:

```
/* Rating Star Widgets Style */
.rating-stars ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;

  -moz-user-select:none;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
}
.rating-stars ul > li.star {
  display:inline-block;
}

/* Idle State of the stars */
.rating-stars ul > li.star > i.fa {
  font-size:2em; /* Change the size of the stars */
  color:#ccc; /* Color on idle state */
}

/* Hover state of the stars */
.rating-stars ul > li.star.hover > i.fa {
  color:#FFCC36;
}

/* Selected state of the stars */
.rating-stars ul > li.star.selected > i.fa {
  color:#FF912C;
}

.rated-stars{
  i.fa{
    font-size:2em;
    color:#FFCC36;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you need is to look at [polymorphic-associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). It allows you to have a model which can belong to more than one model. In your case something like:

```
class Rating < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :rateable, polymorphic: true
end
 
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ratings, as: :rateable
end
 
class Freelancer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ratings, as: :rateable
end
```

and then add [ratyrate](https://github.com/wazery/ratyrate) to `Rating`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have added my code above. But I am stuck on `rater` in `Rate` model. I can't figure it out. I also tried with `Rating` model as `rater` as you suggested, but how will be the `rating_for` tag?